# Android contact added programatically not showing data fields

Tags: android, contacts, android-syncadapter

I have some working code that, given an existing contactID, applies changes to existing fields in the contact (e.g. photo, phone number, email, etc.) and adds fields to the contact.

This code was taken from some sample and works perfectly and I can see all the modified/new fields of an existing contact.

The problem is if I create a contact programmatically, I see it as a contact that includes only the picture, and a field that belongs to my syncadapter that shows the icon, status and presence of the contact. No other fields are visible (e.g. phone, email, etc).

I tried adding the contact both as an account type belonging to my syncadapter and a google account. In both cases the result was the same.
When debugging the code, it looks like everything is succeeding...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was trying to update data on an existing contact.
The solution was to create my own RawContact with the relevant data and then joining it to an existing contact.
The system then allowed me to modify data on other raw contacts belonging to the same contact.